# Website Testing with multiple languages and multiple domains

Tags: testing, localization, qtp

How do you go about testing a site before deployment across multiple languages(English, German and Spanish) and multiple domains(.in, .fr, .de etc). If an automatic framework already exists in QTP for testing the site on one domain and in one language can it be easily extended across all other domains and languages ?
Or is there any other more convenient option or tool available to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a built in capability in QTP, object [repository parametrization](http://hpsqtp.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-parameterize-object-repository.html).

You can parametrize the language specific part of the description of test objects in the object repository.